# Android studio crear carpetas en res

Tags: android

soy nuevo con Android studio y se me esta complicando en crear la carpeta layout-small, le doy a new/android resource directory y por mucho que la creo luego no me aparece en el arbol de carpetas pero si en windows.

un saludo

Comment: Debes reiniciar AS, si no puedes buscar la carpeta en el directorio de tu AS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La carpeta la has creado correctamente, para poder visualizarla debes cambiar el formato de vista de tus archivos, ahora mismo estas trabajando en `android`, cambia a `project` y ahí podrás ver el directorio.

Primero cambia de `android` a `project`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En `project` navega hasta la ruta `main` donde estan las carpetas `res` y `java`, metete en `res` y ahí encontraras el directorio creado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Funciona bien con las ultimas actualizaciones de Android studio? yo he creado todas las carpetas y al final solo me coge las de sw360dp

Answer (score 0):

Una vez que la creas, trata de buscarla con tu Explorador de Windows, para verificar que te este creando la carpeta.

Comment: La carpeta si que la crea en windows pero no aparece en el programa Android studio